# is Hibernate 3.x compatible with Tomcat 5.0.x?

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat

So, I have a godaddy account and I wanted to use it for a small hibernate/spring project... they host java, but they only have the Tomcat 5.0.27 version... would I have to go to a previous version of hibernate or would it work just fine?

thanks,

Johan

Answer (score 5):

Completely orthogonal.  They have no knowledge of each other at all.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate versions prior to 3.6 require Java 1.4 (or Java 1.5 if you want to use annotations). That's all.